# Type error with Hasura array data type: "A string is expected for type : _int4"

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a table I created in the Hasura console. A few of the columns are integer `int` types and I get the expected data type: `Maybe<Scalars['Int']>`.

However, a few needed to be an array of integers so I created those in the Hasura SQL tab:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    add my_ids integer[];
```

If I populate those in GraphiQL with the following query variable everything works just fine:

```
{
  "my_ids": "{1200, 1201, 1202}",
}
```

However, when I try to make the same request from my front-end client, I received the following error: `A string is expected for type : _int4`. Looking at the datatype, it is slightly different than the preset (in the data type dropdown) integer types: `Maybe<Scalars['_int4']>`.

Is there a way to get the array of integers to be `Maybe<Scalars['Int']>` like the preset integer types? Or if there isn't, how can resolve the issue with my request throwing errors for this `_int4` type?

Comment: Are you making the request using `"{1200, 1201, 1202}"` i.e. as a string? or are you trying to use a an array? i.e. `[1200, 1201, 1202]`

Comment: The values are being returned to me as integers when I query for them. I followed the PostgreSQL documentation that was referenced from the Hasura docs [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT).

Comment: Actually, It looks like they are not available yet. https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/pull/2243

You'll have to use JSONB for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hasura cannot process array but it can process array literals.

I've written a function to help you to transform your array into array literal before mutation:

```
const toArrayLiteral = (arr) => (JSON.stringify(arr).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}'))
...
myObject.array = toArrayLiteral(myObject.array) // will make ['friend'] to {'friend'}
```

Good luck